# How to delete directories in SAS

Tags: sas

Is there any macro that will automatically delete directories with files in them? I cannot delete the files manually as I am on VPN so I would need to write a SAS program that automatically deletes the directory.

Comment: As your question is operating system related, add a tag for the operating system used.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option you can pass an x command. If it's locked down this won't work. This allows you to pass system commands to the OS.

```
 x 'rmdir /s path_to_folder';
```

Comment: What if the X option does not exists?

Comment: FDELETE() exists as well.

Comment: Ok, thank you! What I don't like in FDELETE is that we must to write a loop, and read the files one by one.

Comment: You're not 'reading the files' you get a list of the files from the directory, which can be recursive and then delete them all at once?

Comment: I know how to delete one file at once using its reference : ficEff=fdelete('fileReference'). What is then, the syntaxe of deleting a LIST of files? Is it by using a list of references?

Comment: Maybe start your own question now.

Answer (score 1):

if your administrator has not disabled the `x` command you can try:

`x "rm -R /folders to delete";`